# Importing CSV into Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, cell-array

Chemical composition of a certain material

Hi,

I am trying to import the below mentioned data in CSV format in matlab, which is [1000x10] in dimensions.

HCL;H2SO4;CH4; SULPHUR;CHLORINE;S2O3;SO2;NH3;CO2;O2
144 2   3   141 140 6   7   137 136 10  11  133

13  131 130 16  17  127 126 20  21  123 122 24

25  119 118 28  29  115 114 32  33  111 110 36

108 38  39  105 104 42  43  101 100 46  47  97

96  50  51  93  92  54  55  89  88  58  59  85

61  83  82  64  65  79  78  68  69  75  74  72

73  71  70  76  77  67  66  80  81  63  62  84

60  86  87  57  56  90  91  53  52  94  95  49

48  98  99  45  44  102 103 41  40  106 107 37

109 35  34  112 113 31  30  116 117 27  26  120

121 23  22  124 125 19  18  128 129 15  14  132

12  134 135 9   8   138 139 5   4   142 143 1

I am able to import this data through my code

```
fid = fopen(uigetfile('.csv'),'rt');
FileName = fopen(fid);
headers = fgets(fid);    %get first line
headers = textscan(headers,'%s','delimiter',';'); %read first line
format = repmat('%f',1,size(headers{1,1},1)); %count columns n makeformat  string
data = textscan(fid,format,'delimiter',';'); %read rest of the file
data = [data{:}];
```

I am getting data in matrix form in variable data [1000x10] and name of all the components like HCL, H2SO4 in a cell array named headers{1x1}.

Now I have two questions like the built in import feature in matlab you have flexibility to import data as separate column vectors, numeric matrix,cell array and table format. Is it possible to do as such through code, like i get column vectors with their name HCL with [1000x1] and H2sO4 with [1000x1] in my workspace after import and so on all the column vectors with their names with [1000x1]dimensions.
if yes then help me please...?

If above mentioned is not possible then i can do alternatively that now I have names of column vectors in headers cell array, how I can extract those name and use those names as column vector names through code and I can assign data from data matrix [1000x10] to each column vector with their corresponding names.

like if i say

```
x = headers {1*1}{1*1}; i will get x = "HCL" 
x = genvarname(x); I will get x= x0x22HCL0x2 BUT 
I want that x get replaced with HCL.and then I assign 
HCL = data(:,1) and same like this other variables H2SO4,SULPHUR, CHLORINE.
You can say i try to implement the import feature of column vector through     my code.
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue. thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like, you can use the two data types to create a table in MatLab.  I'm not terribly familiar with its use, but it seems to be well documented.  I'm sure someone else can expand upon this.

Edit:

After re-reading your question, I think this is closer to what you are after.

```
n=10;
what='HCL';%change this to any of the strings you interested in
numstr = repmat('%f',1,n);
hdrstr = repmat('%s',1,n);

headers = textscan(headers,hdrstr,'delimiter',';');
headers = headers(1,:)
data = cell2mat(textscan(fid,numstr,'delimiter',';'));

datout = data(:,strcmp(headers,what));%datout will be 1000x1 HCL data
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can loop through these appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in [readtable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) function?

You can access each column of the table by using the named column header.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you asked for, but I would convert to a struct:

```
x=cell2struct(num2cell(data),headers,2)
```

reason is simple, selecting for example the third row with individual variables is not possible. With a struct simply use `x(3)`

If at some point you need the vectors you originally asked for and you can't use the strcut, use `[x.HCL]`